# Simplification of Nested Summations

Tags: functions, summation

Given the following code:

```
for i = 1 to n
    for j = 1 to i
        for k = j to (i+j)
            r = r + 1
        end
    end
end
print r
```

I get:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^i\left(\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}1\right)\right) = \frac{1}{3}n(n+1)(n+2)
$$

using [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28sum%20%28sum%201%20k=j%20to%20i%2bj%29%20j=1%20to%20i%29%20i%20=%201%20to%20n), I can get to the left hand side but have no idea how to reach the function of n by myself. I really need to learn this but I don't even know what the process is called! Any pointers on where to learn the method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Start from the inside and continue. The result of the most inside summation is just ($1+i$) which now you have to sum from $j=1$ to $j=i$. So, the result of the middle summation is $i(i+1)$ which is the sum of numbers plus the sum of their squares. So, you should end with the formula.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I had got the inner most as being (1+i), hopefully correctly, from: (i+j+1-j).

I'd also got that this needed to happen i times, and had multiplied out i(i+1) to get i²+i.

I still don't know where to go next though, how does one get rid of the i?

Comment: You have to take the sum of the $i$'s and the sum of the $i^2$'s.

Comment: Okay so I need to substitute this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/d/6/0/d607ea9d4fb4f76540798a6979299b09.png for i². And this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/1/0/4/104e27d6b1bd59741d2e436c67209b83.png for i. I didn't know about either of those equations. Then I need to simplify it down which I think I can do.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the identity
$$
\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{j}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\tag{1}
$$
which is proven in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398771/proving-sum-m-0m-binommkk-binomkm1k1).

Then compute
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}1
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ii+1\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n2\binom{i+1}{2}\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}2\binom{i}{2}\tag{5}\\
&=2\binom{n+2}{3}\tag{6}\\
&=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{3}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: summing $i+1$ terms of $1$
$(3)$: summing $i$ terms of $i+1$
$(4)$: value of binomial coefficient
$(5)$: substitution $i\mapsto i-1$
$(6)$: apply $(1)$
$(7)$: value of binomial coefficient

---

**Another Proof of $\mathbf{(1)}$:**

The recursion that defines [Pascal's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) is
$$
\binom{j+1}{k+1}=\binom{j}{k}+\binom{j}{k+1}\tag{8}
$$
Thus, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{j}{k}
&=\sum_{j=k}^n\left[\binom{j+1}{k+1}-\binom{j}{k+1}\right]\tag{9}\\
&=\sum_{j=k+1}^{n+1}\binom{j}{k+1}-\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{j}{k+1}\tag{10}\\
&=\left(\binom{n+1}{k+1}+\color{#C00000}{\sum_{j=k+1}^n\binom{j}{k+1}}\right)
-\left(\binom{k}{k+1}+\color{#C00000}{\sum_{j=k+1}^n\binom{j}{k+1}}\right)\tag{11}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{k}{k+1}\tag{12}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\ \:(9)$: Apply $(8)$
$(10)$: split the sum into two and reindex the first ($j\mapsto j-1$)
$(11)$: pull the $j=n+1$ term out of the first sum and the $j=k$ term out of the second
$(12)$: cancel identical sums
$(13)$: $\binom{k}{k+1}=0$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. My level of maths isn't great and I don't really understand some of the steps here, namely lines 3-5. The process described in the comments of Claude Leibovici's answer seem to make more intuitive sense to me. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: @CharlieEgan: If you are familiar with the binomial coefficients, $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and $\binom{n}{3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$. The other step is a change of variables from $i$ to $i-1$ which moves the limits of summation up $1$.

Comment: I know the formula for combinations, but evidently not well enough to understand your answer, sorry :(

Comment: @CharlieEgan: I have added a more detailed explanation. I hope that helps.

Comment: I can see that choosing 2 elements from n would give $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ yet I can't see how it enables us to progress from 3 to 4, or 4 to 5 for that matter.

Comment: I should explain my lack of ability. Basically we've started a new course, I'm in second year at university studying computer science, and it's a big step up. We've not really been prepared for this level of maths. Sorry for being a bit slow... :)

Comment: @CharlieEgan: I've added a proof of $(1)$, in addition to the one cited. This proof might be easier to follow.

Comment: I'm really sorry but it's not. What I'm sure is a very elegant solution is, I'm afraid, beyond me. Claudes answer gave me a starting point that allowed me to follow steps that seemed to make intuitive sense to me. I'd like more than anything right now to be able to read your answer and understand it as if it was a children's story, sadly this is not the case. I do really appreciate you taking the time to contribute though.

Comment: @CharlieEgan: perhaps if you would pick out a step and say what confuses you. I don't know what to add to make it more helpful without some hint of what is troubling you. However, if all you want to do is apply
$$\sum_{k=1}^n1=n\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n^2+n}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}$$ without understanding how each is derived, then my answer is too much information and you should probably just ignore it.

Comment: I really do appreciate you taking the time like this, but that, _just_ applying it, is all I need to do, and even that is tough for me! Thanks again for all your input, but luckily, I don't think I need to understand the process to this level. Cheers.